# Git GUI push to specific branch

Tags: git, git-gui

How can i push to specific branch in remote with GIT gui. I can't seem to find an option for it. Let say i want to push to a specific branch name 'branchOne'. How could it be done? I am pushing to gitlab.

[image]

Comment: You can't push from one branch to an *unrelated* branch. This isn't pushing, it's merging. Pushing means that changes you've made to a branch locally, are sent to its related remote branch - which should have the same name to avoid confusion. Checkout `branchOne`, merge the changes from `master` and then push your local `branchOne` to the remote

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you mean i choose branch -> create -> tracking branch to check out branchOne?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you push something to a remote server you are pushing a specific branch. In your case you have a master branch so changes in your master branch will be added to remote.

In case you have two branches **master** and **development** then while pushing you will have to specify which branch you want to push in GIT GUI, so code committed in that branch will only be added to remote repository.

So technically what you are asking for is not required.

Comment: so how could i clone a specific branch?

Comment: You don't have to clone a specific branch. If you cloned the remote repository, you've already clonded the branches. All you need is to switch to your local "copy" of the branch

Comment: When you clone a repository u clone all the branches and commits with it you cannot clone a specific branch.

Answer (score -2):

In git you need to specify the name of the branch to `pull` or to `push`.
In older versions it was not mandatory but it had some side effects.

If you wish to push to master you should specify the branch name in your case the tool let you select the desired branch.

---

#### ***`SourceTree`***

The best GUI tool out there today is [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), its much better than the git tool you are using.

---

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional `matching` semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the `simple` semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   `matching` semantics, you can set the variable to "matching", for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.