# Git Gui push to branch "main" instead of "master"

Tags: git, github, git-gui

Git Gui by default only allows me to push to the branch `master`, but I would like to push to the branch `main`.

When I push I am just asked:

[image]

So the main branch does not appear.

I still have some old Git-projects where we use a `master` branch, but in the new Git Projects we use the GitHub default `main` branch.

1.) How can I choose the branch I want to push to in general?
<sub>(Basically the same question as in [Git GUI push to specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597781/git-gui-push-to-specific-branch), but with focus on the `main` branch. A detailed beginner friendly answer would be nice, since I have never used multiple branches before GitHub changed from `master` to `main`. For example I don't know how to checkout another branch in Git Gui. I think I created the `master` branch with Git Gui automatically unintentionally? Maybe it would be better to delete the `master` branch and only use the `main` one?)</sub>

2.) Can I make the `main` branch my default branch instead of `master`. Do more up to date versions of Git Gui do this by default?

Comment: maybe in arbitrary location u can choose "origin/Main"?

Comment: You can rename your master branch to main by creating main using `git checkout -b main master` and deleting master using `git branch -d master`.

Comment: @dan1st Where do I enter these commands and will Git Gui always automatically use the `main` branch after I entered this command once per project?

Comment: You can just enter them in the command line in the project directories.

Comment: @Ivan This does not work. Pressing the push button after entering the arbitrary location "origin/main" or "origin/Main" does not have any effect :(

Comment: @dan1st What do you mean by "creating main"? There is already a main branch on GitHub where my colleagues pushing their code. I don't want to override that. If I first fetch from origin and locally merge, there should be no risk of overwriting their code?

Comment: The command creates a new **local** branch `main` from the local `master` branch. The two commands combined rename the local branch from `master` to `main`.

Comment: @dan1st: Your solution worked very well for me:)